# Error calling class method in obj-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm new to obj-c and I'm trying to create a Cordova plugin for the square connect lib.

I am trying to create an instance of the class [SCCAPIRequest](https://github.com/square/SquarePointOfSaleSDK-iOS/tree/master/Sources).
but I get an error:

```
 error: no known class method for selector
  'requestWithCallbackURL:amount:locationID:notes:metadata:supportedTenderTypes:error:'
```

Here is my function

```
- (void)requestCharge: (CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command {
int amount = [[command.arguments objectAtIndex: 0] intValue];
NSDictionary* options = [command.arguments objectAtIndex: 1];

CDVPluginResult *pluginResult;

if( amount < 0 || amount == 0) {
 NSLog(@"Error: Ammount to charge is 0");
 NSString *errorResponse = @"Error: Ammount to charge is 0";
 pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult 
 resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_ERROR messageAsString:errorResponse];
}

[self setOptions:options];

NSError *error = nil;
SCCAPIRequest *request = [SCCAPIRequest requestWithCallbackURL:[NSURL 
URLWithString:yourCallbackURLString]
                                      amount:amount
                                locationID:self.locationID
                                      notes:self.note
                                    metadata:self.metadata
                              supportedTenderTypes:self.tenders
                                        error:&error];


NSData *response = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:request];

if(error) {
  pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_ERROR 
  messageAsArrayBuffer:response];
} else {
 pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK 
  messageAsArrayBuffer:response];
}

[self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult 
callbackId:command.callbackId];
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error log says all you need to know. There's no method `'requestWithCallbackURL:amount:locationID:notes:metadata:supportedTenderTypes:error:'`. You're calling a non-existing init method of `SCCAPIRequest`.

If you're going to check out the init methods of that class in its header file, specifically on this link: https://github.com/square/SquarePointOfSaleSDK-iOS/blob/master/Sources/SCCAPIRequest.h, you would see two different init methods that you can use.

```
+ (nullable instancetype)requestWithCallbackURL:(nonnull NSURL *)callbackURL
                                         amount:(nonnull SCCMoney *)amount
                                 userInfoString:(nullable NSString *)userInfoString
                                     locationID:(nullable NSString *)locationID
                                          notes:(nullable NSString *)notes
                                     customerID:(nullable NSString*)customerID
                           supportedTenderTypes:(SCCAPIRequestTenderTypes)supportedTenderTypes
                              clearsDefaultFees:(BOOL)clearsDefaultFees
                returnAutomaticallyAfterPayment:(BOOL)autoreturn
                                          error:(out NSError *__nullable *__nullable)error;

+ (nullable instancetype)requestWithCallbackURL:(nonnull NSURL *)callbackURL
                                         amount:(nonnull SCCMoney *)amount
                                 userInfoString:(nullable NSString *)userInfoString
                                     merchantID:(nullable NSString *)merchantID
                                          notes:(nullable NSString *)notes
                                     customerID:(nullable NSString*)customerID
                           supportedTenderTypes:(SCCAPIRequestTenderTypes)supportedTenderTypes
                              clearsDefaultFees:(BOOL)clearsDefaultFees
                returnAutomaticallyAfterPayment:(BOOL)autoreturn
                                          error:(out NSError *__nullable *__nullable)error __deprecated_msg("Use requestWithCallbackURL:amount:userInfoString:locationID:notes:customerID:supportedTenderTypes:clearsDefaultFees:returnAutomaticallyAfterPayment:error: instead.");
```

So use one of those to properly make an instance of `SCCAPIRequest`.

Comment: Could you point me to a tutorial on how to use 'init' methods? Like I said I'm new to obj-c.

Comment: Hi @DanielCuesta, the codes I posted above is the function you would call when making a new instance of the `SCCAPIRequest`. You just simply call it like what you did above: `SCCAPIRequest *request = [SCCAPIRequest ...... lalala]`

Comment: I was able to compile, but I get an error `SCCAPIRequest encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Comment: Updating Question.

Comment: Use the two methods above, Daniel.

Comment: I had a typo in one of the parameter names in my call.